# Proof Clarification Regarding Lay's Demonstration that $S$ is closed iff $S$ Contains All its Accumulation Points

Tags: real-analysis

Here is an excerpt from the proof that the set $S$ is closed iff $S$ contains all of its accumulation points.

Note: The set $S'$ is the set of all the accumulation points of $S$.

> Conversely, suppose that $S' \subseteq S$. We shall show that $\mathbb{R} - S$ is open. To this end, let $x \in \mathbb{R}-S$. Then $x \notin S'$, so there exists a deleted neighborhood $N^*(x;\epsilon)$ such that $N^*(x;\epsilon) \cap S = \varnothing$. Since $x \notin S$, the whole neighborhood $N(x;\epsilon)$ misses S; that is, $N(x;\epsilon) \subseteq \mathbb{R}-S$. Thus, $\mathbb{R}-S$ is open and $S$ is closed.

My question is, if we deleted the sentence

> Then $x \notin S'$, so there exists a deleted neighborhood $N^*(x;\epsilon)$ such that $N^*(x;\epsilon) \cap S = \varnothing$.

would we be able to conclude that $N(x;\epsilon)$ still has an empty intersection with $S$? Or is the answer to my question no due to the fact that just knowing that $x \notin S$ is not enough to deduce that none of the points in $N(x;\epsilon)$ do not belong to $S$?

Sourse: Analysis with an introduction to proof, 5th edition, 2014, Steven R. Lay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An accumulation point is defined to be a point for which there exists a *deleted neighborhood* that doesn't intersect $S$. In that step of the proof, the fact that $S^\prime\subseteq S$ is used. But if you omit the part which says "Then $x\notin S^\prime$, so there exists a deleted neighborhood $N^*(x;\epsilon)$ such that $N^∗(x;\epsilon)\cap S=\varnothing$.", then non of the hypotheses helps you to conclude that $N(x;\epsilon)\cap S=\varnothing$.